# Convert JSON presentation of Strings to Strings

Tags: json, mongodb

I have JSON objects in MongoDB that look like this `{"0":"2","1":"1","2":"2","3":"1"}"`, and I want to convert them into Strings that look like this `"2121"`. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Try with $concat https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using concat function that can be achieve

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{ 
   $project:{number:{$concat:[ "$0", "$1", "$2","$3" ]}}
}
])
```

Hopes that helps